# XML tags validation in internet explorer

Tags: xml

I have a simple xml with tags but when displayed in IE, the data shows up. No error displayed.

```
    <name>John</name>
    <phone>111-222-3344</email>
```

How to validate this error without programming? XML notepad tool does not even open the XML.

Comment: Is it the entire XML file, or just a fragment of it?

Comment: Is that the entire XML file? If so, IE is being nice, because it's not well-formed XML, and should not properly parse in any XML tool.

Comment: <cake name="banananut">
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
    <sugar>1cup</sugar>
    <nuts>1cup</puts>
</cake>

Comment: That was a fragment of it, added a full xml in comments.